# Symbol not found in flat namespace '_FT_Done_Face' from reportlab with Python@3.9 on macOS 12

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, reportlab

I have a django project using easy-thumbnail as a dependency.

Installing all packages with pip is working as expected, but when I try to run my app I get this error:

```
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'backend.templatetags.get_thumbnail': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/_renderPM.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_FT_Done_Face'
```

The error is raised from reportlab which is a dependency of easy-thumbnail. As far as I understand, reportlab is not able to find freetype. But it is installed correctly imho.

I'm using macOS 12.0.1

I installed Python and freetype via Homebrew. pkg-config says, that freetype2 is available at the expected paths.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

---

*Edit*

I did `otool -l` on the failing .so-file and this is, what I get (here I'm running it again in a venv):

```
/Users/markusgerards/.pyenv/versions/myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/_renderPM.cpython-39-darwin.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
```

I suspect that freetype should be listed there... right?

Comment: Am I right in guessing you're running on Apple Silicon? You might be mixing and matching architectures (x64/arm64...)

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm trying to shift to Apple Silicon. How can I find out if I'm mixing architectures?

Comment: See what `import platform; print(platform.architecture())` says in your project's Python shell to find out which architecture Python is running with, to begin with.

Comment: This returns `('64bit', '')`
And `platform.machine()` ouptuts `arm64`

Comment: How did you install `reportlab`? Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling it, or maybe upgrading it? Also, it seems you're not using a virtualenv – you really should be.

Comment: reportlab was installed as a dependency from easy-thumbnail which is listed in my requirements.txt. I first tried to run it within a virtualenv managed by pyenv. I tried several (force-)installs within the virtualenv and when they all failed I tried it running directly without the venv. I'm confused that the installation of the package from pip works without any error...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I reinstalled reportlab with this command:

```
pip install reportlab --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext
```

This forced pip to actually build the package and now everythings works as intended!

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue I experienced right away. It happened after I migrated from an Intel Mac to an ARM Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer didn't work for me in a 3.8 venv on OS 12.1 with an M1 Max chip.; same error: `symbol not found in flat namespace '_FT_Done_Face'`

Comment: Does not work 2022

Comment: Does not work either. Not sure what else to try ! ;_0

Comment: This worked for me on an M1 Max Sonoma 14.2.1 with pyenv as of 05/02/2024.

Answer (score 5):

I use M1 Mac Air with Python 3.8 and for some reason, solution from @gerricom didn't work out for me. But, simple `pip uninstall reportlab` and then `pip install reportlab` solved the problem.

Comment: this works for me. 
I'm using python 3.9 and macbook pro m1 chip with macOS monterey

Comment: Not working here, sorry

Comment: Also not working on M1 Max Sonoma 14.2.1 with pyenv as of 05/02/2024.